# discoverpeers in simple android wifip2pmanager code

Tags: android, wifimanager, wifip2p

i going to start a project in android via wifip2pmanager.
it seem the channel successfully created ("initialize").
but for next step my code do not work("discoverPeers or creategroup").
is any problem in below code?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        WifiP2pManager wifiMgr;
        Channel channel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wifiMgr = (WifiP2pManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        channel = wifiMgr.initialize(this,getMainLooper(),null);
        wifiMgr.discoverPeers(channel, new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "discover fail."+arg0, 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "discover succ.", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }); 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google documentation states that "Registering an application handler with initialize(Context, Looper, WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener) requires the permissions ACCESS_WIFI_STATE and CHANGE_WIFI_STATE to perform any further peer-to-peer operations." So you should add these permissions to manifest.xml. The next step in your code then should be handling the various WIFI_P2P_STATE_XXX actions received by the broadcast receiver which you'll supply and register ( usually inside onResume() )